# Free tool for survey like Google Forms, but showing answers for each respondent

Tags: voting

There are 20 people in my group and sometimes we need to vote for several alternatives. Google Forms is an ideal tool for us except it can't show the answer for each person in our group. We need to know not only how many persons vote for each alternative, but also we need to know who are these persons (and who hasn't voted yet)
The voting should be available only for our group.
Is there any free tool that can do it in the needed way?

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the developers of PollUnit. I think our tool could help you. Polls up to 40 participants are free.

If you use our premium feature "invite" only the invited persons can vote and you will see a list of the missing persons in the evaluation section. But I think the free version may suit your needs.

You can take a look at https://pollunit.com